# How to parse this date in java : "12/19/2015 8:00:00 AM"

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm new to java and I'm getting problem parsing this date: "12/19/2015 8:00:00 AM".

Comment: Have you tried <insert search engine of your choice here>?

Comment: which format do you expect?

Comment: What is the problem that you are getting?

Comment: can you tell which format you want convert

Comment: (The duplicate isn't for the exact format, but it should be enough to get you started.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and use the formatting elements that correspond to the string you have:

```
String strDate = "12/19/2015 8:00:00 AM";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date date = df.parse(strDate);
```